# Protege DL query; This reasoner only supports named classes

Tags: owl, protege, pellet, manchester-syntax, hermite

I have an [OWL ontology](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~%20oromero/EUCarRental.owl)in Protege 5. When trying to ask some DL queries

```
DropOff exactly 1
```

This should return all classes that are related by means of exactly to-one cardinality by objectProperty DropOff.

Using **Pellet** reasoner, an exception raises "This reasoner doesn't support named classes". While when using **Hermit** reasoner, things are OK.

I know that a named class is a class with a referent URL.
Here are my points:

- What is the semantic behind using **un**named classes?
- Why named classes are not supported in Pellet?
- can my query be expressed in such a way that is acceptable for Pellet?

Thanks.

Comment: are you actually putting the the semicolon `;` there?

Comment: No, of course I'm not. Sorry I put it in the question by mistake. I edited the question :)

Comment: Can you confirm whether the exact message is "This reasoner doesn't support named classes" or "This reasoner only supports named classes"?

Comment: "This reasoner only supports named classes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in Pellet might be misreported. I have only managed to find the sentence `"This reasoner only supports named classes"` in the Pellet source code (in the `IncrementalClassifier.java` file). This exception is thrown if the incremental reasoning mode is used and queries like 'find all equivalent classes for this class ""' are run - e.g., `DropOff exactly 1` is an anonymous class expression that Pellet incremental does not support.

I don't know if it's possible to not use the incremental feature in Pellet from Protege. If this behaviour is not configurable, then the only workaround would be to modify the Pellet plugin to not work incrementally. This would affect performances for other queries though.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. The exception is "This reasoner only supports named classes" as you said in the above comment, and I was using the incremental Pellet. With a little work around, I reinstalled another Pellet plug-in. with the non-incremental mode things are OK. Thanks.